# I'm getting a 'Memory Error' when running my code [ Python ] - Time Complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I'm trying to write a script that counts the number of 'distinct' (or unique) pairs in my array that have a difference equal to a value K . For example, let's say that I have a list that's [a,a,b,c]. My distinct pairs will be then: (a,b) and (a,c) and (b,c) (Distinct is true if at least one element of a pair isn't in another pair of numbers.)

For the difference, my pair, (a,b) for example, is valid only if a+K = b .

I wrote the two following codes but I'm not sure about the time complexity of the first one and for the second one, I just couldn't think of something less memory-taking.

Thank you!

**1st:**

```
def count(arr, k):
  a = set(arr)
  return sum(x+k in a for x in a)
```

**2nd:**

```
def pairs(k, arr):
    setA = set(arr)
    count = 0
    for x in list(setA):
        if (x-k) in setA:
            count = count +1
    return (count)
```

Comment: the time complexity of both is the same, O(N), you are using basically the exact same algorithm. However, you uselessly create an additional list in `list(setA)`, no need to do that, otherwise, they would require about the same memory

Comment: For the second one, isn't an if in a for loop makes my time complexity O(n^2) ? Thanks !

Comment: An `if` is not a loop, so it won't increase time complexity.

Comment: @helloworld no, it depends what is in the `if`. In this case, it is a constant time operation, so the whole thing is still O(N)

Comment: Both of those ways are O(n). Thay are pretty much identical and probably the best way to do it. I removed my answer since it performed **a lot worse** than either of your solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much Ruhola. How did you compare the scripts?

Comment: I used [my own timer decorator](https://gist.github.com/ruohola/0b96a30e67f87217ae28244a7e2ca2e7).